# Mostrar valor de un campo en otra pestaña

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero hacer un programa que metas un valor en campo en blanco y me saque en una pestaña unos valores de la API de Quandl.

El caso es que quiero introducir un valor en un campo en blanco, darle al botón ok y me aparezcan los valores (en principio quiero que se muestre en la pestaña 1). Pero me he quedado atrancado en ese paso, introduzco el valor pero no se hace nada

```
import quandl
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Invocamos y nos logeamos a la función de la API Quandl
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_privado_XXXXXXXXXX'
campo = StringVar

class Root(Tk):
def __init__(self):
super(Root, self).__init__()
#Definimos la ventana y las pestañas
self.title("Titulocipal de la ventana")
self.minsize(640, 400)
self.configure(background = '#4D4D4D')
controlpestanas = ttk.Notebook(self)
controlpestanas.pack(expan = 1, fill = "both")

self.pestana1 = ttk.Frame(controlpestanas)
controlpestanas.add(self.pestana1, text ="Pestaña 1")

self.pestana2 = ttk.Frame(controlpestanas)
controlpestanas.add(self.pestana2, text ="Pestaña 2")

self.pestana3 = ttk.Frame(controlpestanas)
controlpestanas.add(self.pestana3, text ="Pestaña 3")
self.addfunciones() #llamamos a la funcion addfunciones que añade los valores en la pestaña
# Llamamos a la función de muestra los parametros de la bolsa


#Función en la que se añade funciones a las pestañas

def addfunciones(self):
etiqueta1 = ttk.LabelFrame(self.pestana1, text = "primera etiqueta")
etiqueta1.grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx = 8, pady = 10)

subetiqueta = ttk.Label(etiqueta1, text = "Introduce ticket del valor")
subetiqueta.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = "W")
campo = Entry(etiqueta1, width=20) #Campo en blanco donde se introduce el valor
campo.grid(column=1, row=0)
botonOK = Button(etiqueta1,text = "OK", command)?? # Duda se que el boton no está bien configurado...help :S
botonOK.grid(column=1, row=3)

#Funcion que debe recibir el valor "campo" con el nombre de la empresa, llamar a la base de datos de la API y mostrar el valor
def addgrafbolsa(self,campo)
mostrar_valor = quandl.get_table('ZACKS/FR', paginate=True, ticker=[campo], per_end_date={'gte': '2010-01-01'}, qopts={'columns':['ticker','per_end_date', 'ebitda_margin', 'ret_equity', 'asset_turn']})
mostrar_valor = ttk.Label(etiqueta1)
mostrar_valor.grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = "W")
print(mostrar_valor)

def posicionar_etiquetas(self):
label1 = Label(self, text = "posicion 1")
label2 = Label(self, text = "posicion 2")
label1.place(x = 20, y = 30)
label2.place(x = 50, y = 30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
root = Root()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Para que el código que has metido en la pregunta se vea como código, debes seguir los pasos apropiados. Y tener mucho cuidado con no destruir la indentación original que tenía el programa, ya que entonces nadie podrá probarlo pues la indentación es importante en Python. Mira este enlace https://bit.ly/SOesPASTE

Comment: Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento general (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla). No termina de quedar del todo claro qué es lo que quieres o qué problema estás encontrando. Por favor, edita la pregunta para añadir más detalle.